# How to resolve 'row movement cannot be enabled'?

Tags: sql, oracle

alter table "table name" enable row movement;
Above is the query I tried running. I am also just trying to better understand the action and cause that I am seeing in the display message as well. Thank you.

Error I am getting:

alter table "table name" enable row movement
Error report -
ORA-14662: row movement cannot be enabled
14662. 00000 -  "row movement cannot be enabled"
*Cause:    Attempted to enable row movement for a partitioned table,
although row movement was disabled for a reference-partitioned
child table.
*Action:   Enable row movement for reference-partitioned child tables
before enabling row movement for the parent table.

Comment: You haven't posted a reproducible example so we have to guess.  My guess is that the error message is correct and you need to enable row movement for reference-partitioned child tables before enabling it for the parent table.

Comment: Thank you I will look into that more thoroughly I am roughly new working in oracle and have limited experience.